# Dask data type converting , and re sampling

Tags: bigdata, dask

I am here from the chat room and will post my code

```
df['DateTime']=dd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['KWH/hh (per half hour) '].astype(float)
df=df['KWH/hh (per half hour) '].fillna(0)
df=df.set_index(df['DateTime'], npartitions='auto')
df=df.resample('D').sum()
```

when I run code in prototype 20% of my original data in took around 1.8 minutes but as I go for real data (1.2 gB) the time increase exponentially (more than1 hourse)
I tried same problem with chunks and read csv it is much faster and better than that is generators .
My question is how to enhance the performance I as using pro with 8 cores. Dask should give me better performance by parallel computing righ?

edited one this is my generators:

```
start=time.time()
before= memory_footprint()
dataframes = (pd.read_csv(fname) for fname in filenames)
temp=(remove_unnessasey_data(df,l1) for df in dataframes)
help=(change_structure(t) for t in temp)
for i in(1,688):
    dd.append(next(help))
after= memory_footprint()
du=time.time()-start
```

Comment: `df.set_index(df['DateTime']` - is your data already sorted? I ask, because otherwise, no "generator" method would have worked.

Comment: no it is not but it works  I put that code in edited question please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that you can do this operation "by generator" or "chunks". This suggests to me that your time column is already sorted. As the [doc](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index) points out, you should tell Dask this, so that it doesn't sort your data, which might well be the principal cause for slowness here.

Another suggestion, you start with three row-wise operations one after the other. You may want to try `map_partitions` to do the three in a single step instead.

```
def preprocess(df):
    df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
    df['KWH/hh (per half hour) '] = df['KWH/hh (per half hour) '].astype(float)
    return df['KWH/hh (per half hour) '].fillna(0)

df = df.map_partitions(preprocess)
```

Comment: no the data is sort according to LClID which is  the house id

Comment: I tried df = df.map_partitions(preprocess) but I got error massege:Metadata inference failed in `preprocess`.

You have supplied a custom function and Dask is unable to 
determine the type of output that that function returns @mdurant

Comment: If I were you, I would follow what the message says, and construct a `meta`: a zero-length dataframe with the columns and types you expect from the mapping.